# Writing and Editing eight Plist files form NSbundle to NSDoucumentDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

In My Project, there where eight pList files each file has Twenty Dictionary Data, On click of table view cells by index , i will load eight plist files from NSbundle to NSDoucumentDirectory. and modifying the data in document Directory with when need so every timewhen i load  the files form NSDocument, There should be Changed data , and that will reflect my UI , So My Question is as i was using these many files , and loading them to document directory , Will this process is accepted by apple or not.  Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be OK with Apple?

Comment: I have doubt because , I was saving about eight plist in Document directory.